# How do you use inherited params in angular ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a URL parameter that I want to exist in all states.  The parameter is 'asUser' and it allows admins to look at the app as another user.  I tried:

```
$stateProvider
  .state("root", {
    params: ['asUser']
  })
  .state("root.login", {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "/static/partials/login.html",        
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
  ...
```

But when I go to a url `/login?asUser=123`, I get this error in the console:

```
Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Missing required parameter 'asUser' in state 'root.login'
```

Is there anyway to have a global parameter like this with ui.router, without having to mention it in every state and pass it around everywhere?

Comment: What version of ui-router are you using? I've never seen state params defined like that and they don't do it like that in the docs

Comment: oh ok nvm, I get what you're trying to do. This is just a guess but I try adding the param to the URL of 'root.login' i.e /login/:asUser

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
.state("root", {
    url: '/?asUser'
})
```

You'll still have to handle parameter inheritance on your own, but that should at least make it that parameter valid across all states.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be working. I'm not sure why that should behave differently than `params: ['asUser']` but your example allows me to not repeat the param in all the sub-state URLs. Also, I added `abstract: true` to this root state.

Comment: "I'm not sure why that should behave differently than `params: ['asUser']`" -- because you didn't read the documentation: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#params

Comment: Yes, I did. :) Where in that blurb about `params` does it say that the behavior is different from params specified in `url`? It simply says that you can use it as an alternative, when not specifying a `url`.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work in `angular-ui-router": "0.3.1`
The query params are not accessible in child states unless explicitly added